# How to populate multiple fields in spring mvc <form:select> option?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to SPRING. I want to populate user's first name and last name in my drop down but unfortunately I am not able to do so. Code is :

```
<form:select path="manager.employeeId" id="employeeId"
                    items="${employeeList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="employeeId"
                    cssClass="combo2" />
```

Here name implies the first name as specified. But I also want the user's surname to be displayed in drop down. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue, but didn't find one-line solution. Howeever, you can do it using `c:forEach` loop.

```
<form:select path="manager.employeeId" id="employeeId" cssClass="combo2" />
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employeeList}">
       <form:option value="employee.id">${employee.name} ${employee.surname}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Another way, is to create DTO for displaying, which will contain `getDisplayName()` method.

```
public String getDisplayName(){
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

So you can use `itemLabel="displayName"` in your jsp.